# Can Spark Streaming do Anything Other Than Word Count?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I'm trying to get to grips with Spark Streaming but I'm having difficulty.  Despite reading the documentation and analysing the examples I wish to do something more than a word count on a text file/stream/Kafka queue which is the only thing we're allowed to understand from the docs.

I wish to listen to an incoming Kafka message stream, group messages by key and then process them. The code below is a simplified version of the process; get the stream of messages from Kafka, reduce by key to group messages by message key then to process them.

```
JavaPairDStream<String, byte[]> groupByKeyList = kafkaStream.reduceByKey((bytes, bytes2) -> bytes);

    groupByKeyList.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        List<MyThing> myThingsList = new ArrayList<>();
        MyCalculationCode myCalc = new MyCalculationCode();

        rdd.foreachPartition(partition -> {
            while (partition.hasNext()) {
                Tuple2<String, byte[]> keyAndMessage = partition.next();
                MyThing aSingleMyThing = MyThing.parseFrom(keyAndMessage._2);   //parse from protobuffer format
                myThingsList.add(aSingleMyThing);
            }
        });

        List<MyResult> results = myCalc.doTheStuff(myThingsList);

        //other code here to write results to file

    });
```

When debugging I see that in the while `(partition.hasNext())` the `myThingsList` has a different memory address than the declared `List<MyThing> myThingsList` in the outer `forEachRDD`.

When `List<MyResult> results = myCalc.doTheStuff(myThingsList);` is called there are no results because the `myThingsList` is a different instance of the List.

I'd like a solution to this problem but would prefer a reference to documentation to help me understand why this is not working (as anticipated) and how I can solve it for myself (I don't mean a link to the single page of Spark documentation but also section/paragraph or preferably still, a link to 'JavaDoc' that does not provide Scala examples with non-functional commented code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing different list addresses is because Spark doesn't execute `foreachPartition` locally on the driver, it has to serialize the function and send it over the Executor handling the processing of the partition. You have to remember that although working with the code *feels* like everything runs in a single location, the calculation is actually distributed.

The first problem I see with you code has to do with your `reduceByKey` which takes two byte arrays and returns the first, is that really what you want to do? That means you're effectively dropping parts of the data, perhaps you're looking for `combineByKey` which will allow you to return a `JavaPairDStream<String, List<byte[]>`.

Regarding parsing of your protobuf, looks to me like you don't want `foreachRDD`, you need an additional `map` to parse the data:

```
kafkaStream
 .combineByKey(/* implement logic */)
 .flatMap(x -> x._2)
 .map(proto -> MyThing.parseFrom(proto))
 .map(myThing -> myCalc.doStuff(myThing))
 .foreachRDD(/* After all the processing, do stuff with result */)
```